# How do I parse out just the date from 2017-03-08T19:41:26Z?

Tags: bash, command-line, date, string

I am trying to parse out just the date from `2017-03-08T19:41:26Z`.

The desired output is 2017-03-08.

Comment: Grab the first 11 characters? Is the timestamp in a variable? File?

Answer (score 34):

To extract the part before `T`, with POSIX shells:

```
time=2017-03-08T19:41:26Z
utc_date=${time%T*} # as already said
```

Or to be Bourne compatible or for non-POSIX shells:

```
expr "$time" : '\(.*\)T'
```

Now, note that `2017-03-08T19:41:26Z` is the *zulu time* (another name for UTC), an unambiguous specification of a precise instant in time.

At that time, the date was 2017-03-08 in London, but 2017-03-09 (in the early morning) in Bangkok.

If you wanted to know the *local* date (as opposed to the UTC date) for that time specification, that is for a Bangkok user to get 2017-03-09 and the London user to get 2017-03-08, there are a few options.

With GNU `date`:

```
time=2017-03-08T19:41:26Z

date -d "$time" +%F
```

(easy as GNU date recognises that zulu format out of the box)

Same with `ksh93`:

```
printf '%(%F)T\n' "$time"
```

With `zsh` built-ins:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs unix_time %Y-%m-%dT%TZ $time &&
strftime %Y-%m-%d $unix_time
```

(you can replace `%Y-%m-%d` with `%F` on systems like GNU ones where `strftime()`/`strptime()` support it).

Similar with `busybox date`:

```
unix_time=$(date -u -D %Y-%m-%dT%TZ -d "$time" +%s)
date -d "@$unix_time" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: busybox could convert in one step: `busybox date +'%F' -u -D '%FT%T%Z' -d "$d"`. No need to get the seconds `%s` first. Using the '-u' option makes the output located in ZULU timezone, no need to use `TZ`.

Comment: @sorontar. Thanks for the ksh93 typo. Well spotted. Fixed now. For busybox, the point is to parse the date in the zulu timezone, but output it in the user's timezone, not zulu (so the Bangkok user gets 2017-03-09), so we can't use -u here for both. I still changed the TZ=UTC0 for the shorter -u on the parsing step.

Comment: @sorontar, not sure what  you mean. `TZ=Asia/Bangkok busybox date -D %FT%TZ%z -d "${date}+0000" +%F` could in theory work if `busybox` was linked to the GNU libc whose `strptime()` accepts that `%z` as an extension. I did try it yesterday with Debian's `busybox` built statically and it didn't work. Tried again with  a busybox dynamically linked to the glibc and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @sorontar, the glibc documentation has: _**Note**: Currently, this is not fully implemented.  The format is recognized, input is consumed but no field in TM is set_

Comment: @sorontar, [the documentation in the current git HEAD of glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=manual/time.texi;h=f94cbe4887cd34977451cce719ce269cd661e396;hb=cccc95f28ace0be4fe97537dbd867c08fbf71a8e#l2060) still says it's unimplemented. Maybe your busybox was built with another libc whose strptime() accepts and implements that %Z, can you tell which it is? (I wouldn't expect `Z` to be a valid timezone name, but I suppose it could treat unrecognised strings as a default of UTC).

Comment: @sorontar, it is the same because the date is parsed and output in the same timezone. i.e. the %Z is ignored (not effective, not implemented), so you don't get 2017-03-09 in the Bangkok timezone because 2017-03-08T19:41:26Z is parsed as 2017-03-08T19:41:26 Bangkok time, not zulu time and output in Bangkok time.

Comment: @sorontar, having said that, looking briefly at the code, it looks like uClibc's strptime may be understanding %z/%Z and it's not uncommon for busybox to be linked against uClibc, so it might work there. I'll give it a try when I have the time.

Comment: You are correct, busybox date has not implemented (yet) the parsing of a TimeZone value in the input string. It is clear now why you use two steps (if it required that the output is in the user locale)

Comment: I removed most of the comments, the two that I left (with your present first comment) should be enough to get the correct idea for other users. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @sorontar, for the record, I also tried busybox built against uclibc and also Android x86 (Android's libc I suppose), %Z/%z are not supported on Android. With uclibc, no error, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Android's strptime() doesn't support %F either so I've changed it to %Y-%m-%d

Comment: @sorontar, sorry, I tested with buildroot, so that was uclibc-ng, not uclibc. uclibc-ng's strptime() clearly ignores the %z/%Z (documented as such in the code to do like glibc), uclibc still looks like it would. I still need to test  that.

Comment: @sorontar, I was also wrong about `%z` (as opposed to `%Z`) being ignored by glibc's strptime(). `strptime()` does parse it but stores it in a tm_gmtoff attribute of the `struct tm`. That attribute is not standard, a GNU extension, and busybox (or `zsh`'s strftime) are not aware of it. And anyway they pass the structure to `mktime()` to convert to epoch time which ignores that field. (so does strftime()).

Comment: Yes, there is a difference between `%z` and `%Z`, which in this case is just *interesting* but doesn't change the results of busybox (or zsh, yet). Thanks for digging down to the end of the issue.

Comment: @sorontar, BTW it's `%z` that recognises `Z` as meaning zulu time in glibc's  `strptime()` (since 2015 2.23) (but just to set tm_gmtoff to 0 which as we found is pointless here). `%Z` in `strptime()` can't really work as things like `CST` have different meaning for different people in different parts of the world. Anyway, that was an interesting discussion. Thanks for keeping me on my toes.

Comment: Yep, CST is a bad way to use a world wide unique name. Add that you need to use something like PST (Pacific Standard Time) in Los_Angeles (USA)(late autumn to early spring) and PDT (Pacific Daylight Time) for the rest. (one example; also happens in Paris-CE or Sydney-Australia, but the DST is six months later, in December. Yes, they have summer in December). Two codes for the same city. Add to that that the date in which the DST was effective have changed many times in the past and you are in for a lot of Pain. Simplify, just use TZ=America/Los_Angeles, valid for any time in the past. :-)

Comment: Just to give the [link to Time Zone strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (valid around the named big (with biggest population) city)

Answer (score 14):

Using `cut`:

> cut - remove sections from each line of files
>
> -d, --delimiter=DELIM
>      use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
>
> -f, --fields=LIST
>      select only these fields;  also print any line that contains  no
>      delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified

```
echo "2017-03-08T19:41:26Z" | cut -d T -f 1
```

Answer (score 10):

In Bash, you can use a number of operations in the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) of a variable:

```
timestamp='2017-03-08T19:41:26Z'
date=${timestamp:0:10}          # pick 10 characters starting at position 0
date=${timestamp%T*}            # remove everything starting at the 'T'
```

(`${variable%pattern}` is actually part of the standard shell language, and supported also by simpler shells like `dash`.)

These are of course just simple substring operations. If you want to
actually *parse* the date, you'll have to do something else. The substring expansion will of course fit nicely here since the format is fixed-width. But you may want to check that the values are valid etc.

Answer (score 6):

So just find all the numbers-dash-numbers-dash-numbers? This would work with longer strings/lines, even without any "T"s immediately after the date.

```
grep -o "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]"
```

Or equivalently, but slightly shorter using curly bracket "repeats/multiples"

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}'
```

Ex:

```
$ echo 2017-03-08T19:41:26Z | grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}'
2017-03-08
```

If there's not many other dashes in the input, you could search for any 4 characters, a dash, two characters, a dash, two more characters:

```
$ echo 2017-03-08T19:41:26Z | grep -o '....-..-..'
2017-03-08
```

Answer (score 6):

Bash variable substitution can cover this.

```
OLD="2017-03-08T19:41:26Z"
NEW=${OLD%T*}
echo $NEW
2017-03-08
```

*${string%substring}* - Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.  More details at [Manipulating Strings](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Answer (score 4):

## date

If you could use GNU date, this will do what you want:

```
$ d='2017-03-08T19:41:26Z'
$ date +'%F' -ud "$d"
2017-03-08
```

Use the `-u` option to avoid some issues with the value of `TZ` (or locale).

If you need a date value in some other location, the value of the local TZ will work with this option:

```
$ date +'%F' -d "$d"
2017-03-08               # May change in some locales.
```

Or you can choose to use some specific value for TZ:

```
$ TZ=Asia/Kolkata date +'%F' -d "$d"
2017-03-09               # next day in India.
```

Note that Kolkata is the present name for the old Calcuta.

## shell

1. [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) could do it only if the value is an integer (in seconds):

   ```
   $ printf '%(%F)T\n' $(date +'%s' -d "$d")
   2017-03-08
   ```

   However bash is afected by the value of `TZ` (or locale):

   ```
   $ TZ=GGG+3 bash -c 'printf "%(%FT%T)T\n" $(date +"%s" -ud "$1")' sh "$d"
   2017-03-08T16:41:26Z
   ```

   Note the **T16:** above (not 19).
2. [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) could do both conversions (to seconds and the format):

   ```
   ksh$ printf '%(%F)T\n' "$d"
   2017-03-08
   ```

   But is equally affected by TZ (or locale):

   ```
   $ TZ=GGG-7 ksh93 -c 'printf "%(%FT%T)T\n" "$1"' sh "$d"
   2017-03-09T02:41:26
   ```

   Note the **09T02** (not `08T19`)
3. [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox) just needs a description of the format (`-D`) of the input (`-d`).

   ```
   $ busybox date -u -D '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ' -d "$d" +'%F'
   2017-03-08
   ```

   Using the `-u` avoids any effect of `TZ` on the output. However, the present version of busybox date has not implemented yet the parsing of a TimeZone value (`-0400`). But it may in the future, `-z` is a protection for the future.

## string

If the value always has a T to indicate time, and it is always in `Z` (zulu time), this string operation will be enough (to get a zulu based date).

```
$ echo " ${d%%T*}"
2017-03-08
```

Comment: timezone/TZ and locale/LANG/LC* are independent; you can change timezone without affecting locale, and you can change locale without changing timezone. Some date formats can be affected by locale (%c and %x at least) but %F should be yyyy-mm-dd (ISO8601) everywhere.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, the locale may change several values. The value of TZ may be set by either (locale or/and environment TZ). It is, however, a single **value**.  That value is what I meant, not other elements of the format.

Comment: You'd want `busybox date -u -D '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ' -d "$d"  +'%F'`. `busybox date` uses the libc's (and busybox has been known to be linked with a wide variety of libcs) `getopt()`/`getopt_long()` to parse options, `strptime()` to parse dates, `strftime()` to format them. Not all getopt()s support options after arguments (and those that do stop doing it when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment), not all `strptime()`s support %Z (and currently those that  do ignore it) or `%F`. `%F` in `strftime()` is more widespread. It's specified though optional in POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

Another way by parsing the string with `awk`:

```
echo 2017-03-08T19:41:26Z | awk -F"T" '{print $1}'
```

Or with `sed`:

```
echo "2017-03-08T19:41:26Z" | sed -e "s/T.*$//g"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `grep` up to the `'T'`

```
echo 2017-03-08T19:41:26Z | grep -Eo "[^T]+" | head -1
```

Comment: In my system this outputs a second line with the time, not only the date as requested by OP. It would work if you take only the first line by piping `head -1` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `perl` parse the whole date string and format it to your desire:

```
#!/usr/#bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp; 
    print Time::Piece -> strptime ( $_, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
}

__DATA__
2017-03-08T19:41:26Z
```

And as a one liner:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lne 'print Time::Piece->strptime($_,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Crude, but purpose-specific: `echo $in_date | sed 's/T.*//g'`

For example:

```
in_date="2017-03-08T19:41:26Z"
echo $in_date | sed 's/T.*//g'
2017-03-08
```